# How to hide http server, restful http service and websocket server behind a single IP and Port

Tags: .net, ssl, proxy, router, tls1.2

**Current Situation**

The server has three ports open:

1. A web server (using `HttpListener` from `System.Net`) for delivering HTML5 content
2. A RESTful service (using `wsHttpBinding` from `WCF`) for providing Request/Response interface
3. A WebSocket server (using `Alchemy` `WebSocket Server`) for providing Publish/Subscribe interface

As the server will be hosted on a Windows 7/10 OS, the `WebSocket` from `.NET 4.5` will not help much because the complete framework is not implemented for Windows 7/10. I might be wrong for this.

**Expected Situation**

There should be only one port to be exposed, i.e. the web server port on SSL/TLS.

We can combine web server and RESTful interface in one, by not using `WCF` but by implementing the RESTful interface embedded in web server. But this will require a major code change (both on server and client side). We would like to tackle this situation by a method which involves minimal code change.

**Question**

How to hide these three servers behind only one exposed web server port securely?
What is a general best practice with a security point of view, to achieve such situation.

Answer (score 0):

A RESTful application is consumed through HTTP/S request. Your webserver will probably listen on either one of standard ports 80 or 8080 to service handle requests.

If by "hide" you mean restricting/blocking connections to these ports you can:

1) Limit connections to this port to a list of known IP addresses through firewall rules. On Linux it is standard to use the **iptables** utility.

2) For the above method to work, connecting clients need fixed IP addresses to work. If your ISP does not assign static IP addresses or your clients are expected to connect from other networks then this method will not work consistently.

3) To address the above problem, you can require that clients first tunnel through a VPN to authenticate before using your API.

Honestly, though, I *don't recommend* the above  unless you are trying to hide (say) a botnet API. More important than hiding server ports is to **protect business resources** by writing a custom *authentication layer* logic to grant clients access to your API. The auth layer can be implemented using a token-based approach (e.g. [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)), public-private keys, or session-based login. This gives you far greater flexibility than firewall rules and server configurations, and is "general best practice" in the design of RESTful applications.

As you mentioned, you *must* enforce the use of HTTPS for client-server data to be encrypted.

**Edit:** <s>Because you are using a single server, it is already given that your port (80/8080) will bind to a single static IP address.</s>

Comment: I hope I did not mean to achieve what you tried to provide solution to. What I want to achieve is host three servers on single IP and port without any code change, e.g. I thought that I could use URLs for this three servers and have a kind of a router to internally route different URLs requests to specific IP port servers. Hope this helps you understanding my question. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It sounds like you want something similar to a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) in that case. A reverse proxy server in this setup would be identifiable by a single IP address, and would route client requests to internal private servers. I am not sure if that is what you need. More detail would help.

Comment: Here is an article describing the above, using Apache: http://iws.io/multiple-web-servers-over-a-single-ip-using-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy/

Comment: bw_0x7c6 : yeah, right, that's something I want to achieve. Gone through Apache reverse proxy server, i will try this and would let everyone know whether with this solution I am able to achive it. Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome. :) Let me know if you want help.